# Acumatica and N-Central API integration

Tags: acumatica

We're looking at integrating N-Central (an IT management app) with Acumatica, but N-Central doesn't support oAuth connections so I don't think we can use Connected Applications to do this.  N-Central only supports basic authentication, but their configuration for connecting to an API only offers a single URL path. Since Acumatica's basic API authentication has a different top level login URL than its actual web service endpoints, we have been unable to determine a way for it to connect to Acumatica's API.  Has anyone else done this successfully, or do you have any suggestions on getting this to work?  Is there any way to connect to the Acumatica API via basic authentication that wouldn't require sending requests to two different top level URLs, but instead the same top level path?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to relay your calls through an Acumatica WebHook. You would need to write the plumbing needed to reach your final destination. With WebHook you can roll your own basic authentication.

Comment: It's a call in, though, not a call out.  Wouldn't a Webhook only be applicable to a call out?

Comment: WebHooks are intended to receive calls.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that instead of the external app (in my case N-Central) making a call into Acumatica, with a webhook Acumatica would instead need to make a call out to notify N-Central to make a call back.  Not sure if that's an option.

Comment: OK, I thought you where trying to use the Acumatica API to receive info from a third party system. In terms of out bound notifications you may want to look into using a IPushNodificaitonSender. https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=0413cdf8-a78c-acf2-0c81-ee0dd8fda36b. I have not yet used it but we have some initiatives coming up where I hope to use this to solve them. So I would like to follow up to see if you are able to do anything with this.

Comment: It turns out that a Webhook might actually work.  Looking into the details now, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good to hear, keep me posted on how you make out. WebHooks have all sorts of extra value. Its a powerful feature.